# Возможно ли сериализовать на одной программе и затем десериализовать объект созданного класса на другой программе, без classnotfoundexception

Tags: java, сериализация, serializable

Возможно ли сериализовать на одной программе и затем десериализовать объект созданного класса на другой программе, без classnotfoundexception

Comment: Если обе программы будут обладать знаниями о Вашем классе, то можно, а для этого необходимо подключить jar файл с вашим классом.

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. Существует масса способов сериализации, самый тупой и безнадежный сериализация через интерфейс `Serializable` - пишем через `ObjectOutputStream`, читаем через `ObjectInputStream`  с ручным кастом на нужный класс.

Более модный (сейчас) это сериализация через JSon

Оба способа, особенно первый предполагают импорт класса через либу.

В случае JSon этого можно и не делать, но тогда придется генерировать класс на ходу, например через Java Reflection, но я не буду вам это советовать делать.